# How is it that I am getting different results when I perform batch evaluation of a neural network in tensor flow as opposed to evaluation one by one?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I built a regression convolutional neural network based on [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html) in the tensorflow website.
When I evaluate the result for multiple images at once, I'm getting different results from when I evaluate each of those images one by one.

To be more concrete, for three identical sample images, I get [ `729027.5625  729027.5625  729027.5625]` when I calculate the output for them as a batch, but I get `[ 729026.4375] [ 729026.4375] [ 729026.4375]` when I calculate the outputs for the images one by one.

Any idea why this is the case? The input to my neural network is defined as below:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
```

And when performing batch evaluation, I input a 2 dimensional numpy array of images `(shape = (100, 784))`

EDIT: Please see the below MWE

[mwe_db.npy](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_pNfDLazMhjcUlhRGdmY1ZzOGc)

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5}, session=sess)

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess))

####################
# THE ANOMALY
####################

print "----------------------"
print "THE ANOMALY"
print "----------------------"

mwe_db = np.load("mwe_db.npy")
num_rows = mwe_db.shape[0]

batch_y = y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: mwe_db[0:2, :], keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)
print batch_y

print "----------------------"

for i in xrange(2):
    single_y = y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: mwe_db[i:i+1, :], keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)
    print single_y
```

Comment: Good I found this question. At least I am not the same with this issue.

Comment: Hi, Eddy. Do you figure out the reason of different results? I've encountered a similar question.

Comment: Part of the reason is limited precision of floating point numbers, which means different orders of floating point operations produce slight different results.

Comment: I am getting BIG differences in a case I am studying, so the floating point precision should not be to blame in my case. I have a dataset with 18254 elements. Evaluating it in batches of 1 or 18254 gives slightly different results (so OK for floating point precision) but a batch of 18000 (even if drop_remainder = False, which I believe should produce a batch of 18000 and then one with 254) gives a loss 2,5 times the one for batch of 1. Anyone having similar problems, or some idea for resolution?

Answer (score 1):

So, I do not have a definite answer, but tf.matmul is to blame. The minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
import tensorflow as tf

tf.set_random_seed(123)

# To enforce determinism
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
        inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
        device_count={'GPU': 0}
))

init = np.random.rand(2,50)
x1=tf.Variable(init, dtype=tf.float32)
x2=tf.Variable(init[:1], dtype=tf.float32)

W=tf.Variable(np.random.rand(50,50), dtype=tf.float32)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

r1 = tf.matmul(x1, W)
r2 = tf.matmul(x2, W)
v1, v2 = sess.run([r1, r2])
print(v1[0] - v2)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is different because your model parameters are adjusted differently.  When you perform a batch evaluation each training data of one batch will be processed using the same model parameters. When evaluate one by one your model is adapted after each training data is processed.

Comment: I'm not talking about training. So the parameters remain the same for both the batch evaluation and evaluation one by one. I'll attach a MWE shortly.